# Django Send mail only when one particular field is changed

Tags: python, django, redis

I am using:
[RQ scheduler](https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler)

There is a Job model in my project:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    # Other fields
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=choices.JOB_STATE_CHOICES, default=choices.PENDING_APPROVAL)
```

I have scheduled a task daily at night which will check for all the Jobs that are approved today and send mails to my users about it.

So Query:

```
jobs = Job.objects.filter(status='APPROVED',
                          updated_at__date=datetime.today().date())
```

Problem with this query is how do I know that for this job status field was changed today only.

This query will job a job even if job's title was changed today and status was changed 5 days back.

I need to extract only those jobs whose "status" field was changed today.

Comment: what is the type of your updated_at field in your models?

Comment: It is DateTimeField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use [django-dirtyfields](https://github.com/romgar/django-dirtyfields) and send email immediately or add this job_id to RQ.
Full docs [here](http://django-dirtyfields.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

Or update `updated_at` field only when `status` changes (again django-dirtyfields) by write own save() method like.

```
def save(self):
    if self.status = 'aproved' and 'status' in self.get_dirty_fields():
        # add to RQ
        # or set updated_at = datetime.now()  # if you dont use on_update=datetime.now
    super(...).save()
```